# Outlook Add-In - Enable/Disable Button during Runtime/from Code

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

**Initial Situation:**

We are developing an Add-in for Outlook 2010 in C# with VS.NET 2010 based on Framework 4.0, VSTO, DevExpress WinForm Controls. In Designer we have a Ribbon with a RibbonTab, then a RibbonGroup then a RibbonButton. We're consuming WebServices from within this Outlook Add-in.

**Objective:**

We need to enable/disable the RibbonButtons when the WebService is available/unavailable (from/out of the code)

we've found the following links:

**Links**

Ribbon Object Model Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx
Ribbon Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx
Walkthrough: Updating the Controls on a Ribbon at Run Time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608628.aspx

After hours of trying to figure out how to implement this we deciced to post/ask this question here on SO. Does anybody have a sample code? We tried the IRibbonExtensibility and CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject => we added the RibbonTab, Group and Button and added a subscription to the Click Event => The Event is fired but not handled (in button_Click(...) => System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() is not breaking the code execution)

Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to invalidate the Ribbon at a fairly frequent rate in order to refresh the visibility of each tab/button.  You can do this by subscribing to the Click event (as you've done) and then calling `RibbonObject.Invalidate();`.  Then add a `getEnabled="yourTestFunction"` parameter to each button, with `public bool yourTestFunction(Office.IRibbonControl control)` (Defined in the Ribbon.cs file) returning whether the web service is available or not.

**Keep in mind if the web service is down, each click could hang your application for the amount of time you set on your timeout in the web service check**

**Edit:**
Just realized the _Click event isn't mapped in the Excel COM library, so here's a bit of code that will run each time the cell selection is changed (not as frequent as every click, but hopefully good enough).

`ThisAddIn.cs`:

```
public static Excel.Application e_application;
public static Office.IRibbonUI e_ribbon;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        e_application = this.Application;
        e_application.SheetSelectionChange += new Excel.AppEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler(e_application_SheetSelectionChange);
    }

    void e_application_SheetSelectionChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
    {
        e_ribbon.Invalidate();
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        e_application.SheetSelectionChange -= new Excel.AppEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler(e_application_SheetSelectionChange);
        e_application = null;
    }
```

`Ribbon1.cs`:

```
public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
{
    this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    ThisAddIn.e_ribbon = ribbonUI; //Add this line
}
```

and

```
    public bool getEnabledTest(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        //Whatever you use to test your Web Service
        //return false;
    }
```

`Ribbon1.xml`:

```
 <button id="WebService" label="Use The Web Service" onAction="executeWebService" getEnabled="getEnabledTest" />
```

Comment: You've linked code for excel, unfortunately this won't work for Outlook.  Outlook does not support document level customization of the ribbon unlike your Excel example.

Comment: Aahhh - I saw Outlook, then went to the Excel add-in I was working on.  D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

The following article titled [Adding Custom Dynamic Menus to the Office Fluent User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb462634%28v=office.12%29.aspx) will point you in the right direction.

The below is an example of a dynamically created menu, you can modify the tutorial to fit your particular need.

[image: An example of a dynamically created menu]

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks for the tips. Finally i solved it like this:

i declared a static ribbon object like:

```
public static RibbonIet ribbon {get; set; }
```

in the load event of the Ribbon i assign the Ribbon (this) like:

```
Session.Common.ribbon = this;
```

now i can control the RibbonButton like:

```
Session.Common.ribbon.buttonCreateIncident.Enabled = true;
```

Since the webService call is running in a seperate thread, i had to use a MethodInvoker to change enable/disable the buttons. it goes like this:

```
If (InvokeRequired)
{
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Session.Common.ribbon.buttonCreateIncident.Enabled = true));
}
```

maybe this is of help for someone else.