# It is possible to modify the state of office addin command?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365

I am looking for how to modify the state of office app addin command,but get no results.Can anyone tell me is it possible to dynamically disable or hide the addin command button in Office ribbon after being loaded.It seems the Manifest file only load initially,and can't be changed after that? Thank you!

Comment: is there any way to disable or hide the excel addin command buttons?Can any experts comfirm?

Answer (score 0):

No. At present, the add-in command button only control by the menifest. It is not able to disable dynamically. You can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.

As a workaround, you may also consider developing an VSTO add-in. However it only works for the Windows platform. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237957/outlook-add-in-enable-disable-button-during-runtime-from-code) is an helpful thread.

Comment: ok,Thank you! Find someone already submit similar request IN "Uservoice",hope to see these feature soon. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/11388093-programmatic-access-to-ribbon-commands       https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/13225365-support-dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon